# Try to clean white space in double quote in big content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, conditional-statements

I would like to clean some text:

**Bad content** : ... " Follow my lead" ... (space before 'Follow')

**Good content** : ... "Follow my lead" ...

*For each content in double quote i would like to clean whitespace.*
Great thx advance !

**My content test :**

*Le tour est joué. " Le temps moyen d’une visite dans un magasin muni de caisses automatiques est d’environ une minute. Nous voulons ramener ce temps de passage à 20 secondes ", explique Jan-Willem Dockheer, directeur général d’AH To Go, à " Het Parool " . Apparemment, ça marche : la phase test a permis de confirmer qu’il était possible de sortir en dix secondes du magasin en achetant trois produits.*

**Code :**

```js
var flag = 0;

$("#launchCleaner").click(function() {

  var loadOrigins =$('#txtorigines').val();
  //clean1 = loadOrigins.trim();
    clean1 = loadOrigins.replace(/" /g, '"');
    clean2 = clean1.replace(/ "/g, '"');
    clean3 = clean2.replace(/\./g, '. ');
  $("#txtclean").append(clean3);
});
```

```css
textarea{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 250px;
    resize:none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtorigines"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtclean"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="launchCleaner">Nettoyer le texte</button>
```

Comment: your code works to replace, the problem is that you replace different variables (`clean1`, `clean2`...) but you append the first one `clean1`... try to append the `clean3` to see if it works

Comment: just ! failed but my problem persist. Result example : H To Go, à"Het Parool". Remove whitespace before... i would like --> H To Go, à "Het Parool"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not keeping track of being inside or outside a quoted piece of text. The use of regexes in this case only complicates the issue (in my opinion).

Here is how I would do it: split on the quotes, and keep track of being outside of the quotes or not (initially: yes, then toggle), and construct the new string from there.

```js
$("#launchCleaner").click(function() {
  var text = $('#txtorigines').val();
  var fragments = text.split('"');
  var newText = "";
  var outsideOfQuotes = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
    if (outsideOfQuotes)
      newText += fragments[i];
    else
      newText += '"' + fragments[i].trim() + '"';
    outsideOfQuotes = !outsideOfQuotes;
  }
  $("#txtclean").append(newText);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  resize: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtorigines">Text to " clean up " as an " example ", with some "good text" as well.</textarea>
<textarea id="txtclean"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="launchCleaner">Nettoyer le texte</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your quotes are balanced and no quote escaping in place then you can use this code:

```
let re = /"\s+(?!(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)|\s+"(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/gm;
str = str.replcae(re, '"');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U2h5De/1)

This regex uses an alternation:

- `"\s+`: Match a quote followed by 1+ whitespace (opening quote)
- `(?!(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`: Lookahead that asserts that we don't have even number of quotes ahead
- `|`: OR
- `\s+"`: Match 1+ whitespace followed by a quote (ending quote)
- `(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`: Lookahead that asserts that we have even number of quotes ahead

Answer (score 0):

Under the same assuption as @anubhava

Cant you just `"s*(.+?)\s*"` replace with `"\1"` ?

Comment: is your information a comment or an answer to the question?